# Instanciar classe com nome dinâmico em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, classes

Existe um meio de instanciar uma classe em JavaScript cujo nome encontra-se contido em uma variável do tipo string?

Por exemplo:

```
class User {
  constructor(...args) {
    console.log(args);
  }
}

const className = 'User';

const userInstance = new className();
// const userInstance = new User();
const name = userInstance.name;
console.log(name);
```

Gostaria que a linha:

```
const userInstance = new className();
```

Tivesse o mesmo efeito de:

```
const userInstance = new User();
```

É possível?

Comment: No link a seguir tem algumas formas de fazer, mas envolvem você precisar reorganizar seu código de alguma forma. Veja se alguma te atende: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655616/create-an-instance-of-a-class-in-es6-with-a-dynamic-name/34656123

Comment: Também não. :s   Precisa ser com uma string mesmo. É possível?

Comment: Então, das formas apresentadas no link estamos usando string. Olha este exemplo https://jsbin.com/qedura/edit?js,console

Comment: No exemplo apontado as classes ficam definidas em um objeto constante: `const classes = { Foo, Bar };`. Isso não pode acontecer. Há outra forma?

Comment: Por isso que eu disse que você tem que mexer no código e não coloquei uma resposta. Eu não consegui pensar em nenhuma forma de fazer como você quer. Provavelmente há formas melhores de resolver o seu real problema, mas precisaremos de mais informações.

Comment: Você poderia usar eval, mas dizem que não é seguro(?): `const userInstance = eval('new '+className+'()');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Não vejo a necessidade disso, seu código apenas terá mais linhas, dificultando a manutenção do código.

Simples, utilize o função [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Você pode criar um método para retornar uma instancia da classe.

```
const Classe = (name) => {
    let c = eval(name);
    return new c();
};
```

Veja funcionando:

```js
class User {
  constructor() {
    this._name = 'Luiz';
    this._age = 23;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  get age() {
    return this._age;
  }
}

const Classe = (name) => {
  let c = eval(name);
  return new c();
};

const className = 'User';

const userInstance = Classe(className);
const name = userInstance.name;
console.log(name, userInstance.age);
```

#### Referência

- [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: Sua resposta dá erro: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: Verdade eu mosquei na hora de publicar não tinha prestado atenção.

Comment: Obrigado, é isso mesmo!